# Handling multiple destinations in Azure Data Factory - Data flow pipeline

Tags: azure, etl, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I am having 3 source tables S1, S2 and S3. I am transforming some data and inserting to 3 sink tables D1, D2 and D3. D2 has foreign key relation with D1 and D3 has foreign key relation with D2. I am generating new guid(uuid) using derived column and using those as primary key for 3 tables. While previewing data of derived column, everything looks fine and I am able to see the data correctly. But while debugging, I am getting foreign key relation exception.

I tried disabling constraints and then execution went good. And after I enable it, there was no issues and the relations was proper. So what I doubt is, if the sequence in which the data is inserted is causing the issue. Is their any way by which I can insert D1, followed by D3 and D3 in same data flow pipeline?

See below the screenshot.

[image: Azure Data Factory - Data Flow]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your data flow design UI, click on Settings and set the sink ordering there

[image]

Comment: How can you ensure that BOTH/ALL sinks are written successfully? So that is one database transaction? What if writing to Table1 in Sink1 fails due to some reason (duplicate key or some other constraint), does it still continue to write to Table 2 in Sink2?

Comment: That is an option in the sink under error row handling. You can either "continue on error" or "stop on first error".

Comment: Hi @Mark Kromer MSFT, what if the first Sink 1 succeeds without errors, then it fails in Sink 2? Then my records has already been written to a SQL table in Sink 1 without ensuring that Sink 2 also succeeded. So either all Sinks succeeds or none of them. Like in a SQL Server transaction. So if Sink 2 failed it should roll-back.

Comment: ADF does not have transactional control mechanisms, so rollback is not possible. If you require all of those transactions to write or not at all, then you will need to write them all in a single sink.

Comment: Okay. Thx for clarifying this.